# How to unlink image in php?

Tags: php

I am developing application in PHP. There is image folder. I want to delete image from the folder When user click on delete button. My code is running well. But the UNLINK() function not working. 
My code is

```
unlink('../photo_gallery/'.$image_name['imge_name'],777);
```

I am getting this error

**Warning: unlink() expects parameter 2 to be resource,**

and if i remove 777 then it shows

**Warning: unlink(../photo_gallery/): Permission denied**

Please suggest.

Comment: you dont need to pass `777` in unlink. set your `photo_gallery` folder to 777

Comment: Two tips: 1) Stop typing random parameters unless functions no longer trigger warnings—that stuff is [documented](http://php.net/unlink) 2) If a program doesn't have permission to do something, it can't normally grant permissions to itself; that would beat the whole purpose of having permissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the second parameter. and try this

```
if ( is_file( '../photo_gallery/' . $image_name['imge_name'] ) ) {
   chmod ( '../photo_gallery/' . $image_name['imge_name'] , 777 );
   unlink ( '../photo_gallery/' . $image_name['imge_name'] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in php unlink();
and u must have right to delete that file .

```
$pathOfFile='/var/www/avc/abc.jpg';
unlink($pathOfFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
filename = '../photo_gallery/'.$image_name['imge_name'];

if(file_exists($filename))
{
  chmod($filename, 777);
  unlink($filename);
  echo "file has deleted";
}
else
{
 echo "file not exists";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the right on the folder. The server user running php must have rights on it to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

The process in which you run your application (e.g. from Apache) needs to have write permission to the folder you want to delete from.
check permission on "photo_gallery" folder

Answer (score 1):

You are using this function wrong.

```
unlink('../photo_gallery/'.$image_name['imge_name']);
```

Be sure you have permision (chmod) on folder to write.

http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.unlink.php